# apache balancer, workers on internal IPs

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, mod-proxy

I'm planning to build my first balancer  for one of our website, using apaches mod_proxy and mod_proxy_balancer. Having not so many external IP's I'm thinking about to use each machines Internal IP but I can not decide if this would be a good workaround or not![image]

Is it going to be enough fast? This is a usable or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is what everybody else does (who also doesn't have enough IPv4 addresses).

You could also use your IPv6 addresses internally, if you have gotten them yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. One issue is not really clear for me. How to handle the web contents and mysql database? Is it a problem if the workers are Virtual Machines?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question. :)